# will_paginate - can't change the entry_name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

I am using this:

```
<%= page_entries_info @result, :entry_name => 'result' %>
```

But the in the page what I am getting is:

```
Displaying #<class:0x007fe097746308>s 1 - 20 of 52 in total
```

What I am missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `page_entries_info` method uses a key called `:model`, not `:entry_name`.

This is what it should look like:

```
<%= page_entries_info @result, model: 'result' %>
```

**UPDATE**

You can customize the text that `page_entries_info` generates by editing your `config/locale/en.yml` file (see [here](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki/I18n) for details).

To get "results" to show as capitalized, you would have to make these changes to that file:

```
en:
  will_paginate:
    models:
      result:
        zero:  Results
        one:   Result
        few:   Results
        other: Results
```

Comment: It worked. Any clue why "result" is displayed with small "r" instead of capital "R"?

Comment: Because the string that gets passed into the `page_entries_info` method has a small "r". If you want it to show "Displaying Results 1 - 20 in total" instead, just change `model: 'result'` to `model: 'Result'`.

Comment: I did so, I used 'Result', but the string is still displayed as 'result'.